# SublimeLinter (for sublime 3) background mode for cppcheck doesn't work

Tags: sublimetext3, cppcheck, sublimelinter

I'm trying to setup cppcheck for sublimelinter and I'm not sure why background check isn't working.

The following works:

- "SublimeLinter: Next Error" => finds the next error
- ctrl, s => finds the errors

I double checked and I definitely am in background mode.

Does cppcheck have a background mode for sublimelinter? It would make sense if it doesn't because C is compiled. But just wanted to make sure because I couldn't find anything on this.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

It is a limitation of cppcheck - see https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-cppcheck/issues/10 for explanation.